# How to count characters of a String?

Tags: scala, count, character

I am a pretty newbie to Scala! I would like to count the times a char occurs in a string. How do I do this? I started writing something like this but I find the syntax very hard to grasp. Any help?

```
 var s = "hello"
 var list = s.toList.distinct
 list.foreach(println(s.count(_=='list')))
```

Comment: Are you looking to find the count of total characters in the string or the count of each unique character in the string?

Answer (score 15):

You could try something like this if you wanted a Map of the chars to the counts:

```
val str = "hello"
val countsMap:Map[Char,Int] = 
  str.
    groupBy(identity).
    mapValues(_.size)
```

Which would expand to the more longhand form:

```
str.
  groupBy(c => c).
  mapValues(str => str.size)
```

So to break this down, in the `groupBy` we are saying that we want to group by the individual `Char`s in the String themselves.  This will produce a `Map[Char, String]` like so:

```
Map(e -> e, h -> h, l -> ll, o -> o)
```

Then, you re-map the values portion of that `Map` with the `mapValues` method telling it to use the `.size` of the `String` and not the `String` itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try This :

A tip, Don't use vars.

```
val l = "hello"

scala> l.distinct.toCharArray.map(x=>(x,l.count(_==x)))

res1: Array[(Char, Int)] = Array((h,1), (e,1), (l,2), (o,1))
```

It returns an array of `(Char, Int)` map containing character and its associated count with it.

Comment: This doesn't work. It produces `Array((h,1), (e,1), (l,2), (l,2), (o,1))`. It would work  if it was `l.distinct.toCharArray`

Comment: @paul my bad i pasted the wrong code. i tested it in REPL with both with distinct and without distinct. i have edited that.

Comment: That still does more work than needed. You call count for every repeated letter so repeatedly calculating the same value. If you do the distinct first (l.distinct), count only happens once per distinct letter

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
val s = "hello"
val list = s.toList.distinct
list.foreach(c => println(s.count(_ == c)))
```

I've changed your `var`s to `val`s, since there's no reason for them to be `var`s.

Note that there isn't really any reason to convert your `String` to a `List`. It still works if you don't:

```
val s = "hello"
s.distinct.foreach(c => println(s.count(_ == c)))
```

Comment: P.S. I like cmbaxter's suggested rewrite/rethink.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily group the characters using `groupBy` and then measure the length:

```
scala> "hello".toList.groupBy(identity)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,List[Char]] = Map(e -> List(e), h -> List(h), l -> List(l, l), o -> List(o))

scala> res0.map { case (char, list) => (char, list.length) }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(e -> 1, h -> 1, l -> 2, o -> 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, as a illustration of "there's more than one way to do it"

```
 var s = "hello"  
 s.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]() withDefaultValue 0)
           {(acc, c) => acc updated (c, acc(c)+1)}
 //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] =
     Map(h -> 1, e -> 1, l -> 2, o -> 1)
```

and using a couple more features of Scala. This is basically the same as the groupBy/mapValues answers, except doing it in one pass.